# How to define syntax groups which start at the same position?

Tags: vim

I have next line.

```
start body end
```

I need to define 3 different groups with their own highlighting. The first two are easy, I just execute:

```
syntax region fooLine start=/^/ end=/$/ contains=fooStart,fooEnd
syntax match fooStart /^start/ contained
```

But the third should start with "^start" too (it is important) and it causes many problems.

```
syntax match fooEnd /^start.*\zsend/ contained
```

Does not work. As far as I know when there is the same first character in both 2 groups we should use `contains` attribute, but it is impossible because there is a "body" between "start" and "end". Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have found a solution — so called zero-width atoms. Especially [\@=](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@=) and [\@<=](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@%3C=).

```
syntax region line start=/^/ end=/$/ contains=start,end
syntax match start /^start/ contained
syntax match end /\(^start.*\)\@<=end/ contained
```

Be careful, they are so slow.